# Javascript function dynamically calling from dynamically added code

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

```
$('#arch').on('click', function(){ 
    var x='<p><a href="#" onclick="javascript:dispcontacts()" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"    id="contacts" role="button">Fix a Appointment</a></p>'          
            $('#mydata').html(x);
});


function dispcontacts {
    document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML = "Contacts";
}
```

i am not able to call `dispcontacts()`

How to call dispcontacts?

Comment: You are missing `()`.

Comment: Please get in the habit of checking the browser console for errors.  Your syntax errors will show there and then you can find/solve them yourself.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic as this is a simple typographical error and will not likely help future readers (per SO guidelines).

Comment: because you didn't declare dispcontacts the right way.

Comment: Note:there's no need to include `javascript:` in online html event attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `()`. It should be

```js
function dispcontacts() {
    document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML = "Contacts";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the function paranthesis. It should be

```
function dispcontacts() 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

Here is the jsbin link for the correct code :

http://jsbin.com/vukunamoke/1/edit?html,js,output